# repeating the same numbers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following problem . 
I want this SQL Server 2008 query

```
   select code , name from customer
```

i want to have 2 or more of the same numbers appear in a separate column like this

```
   code  name   repeating_numbers
   x1    mike   1
   x1500 George 2
   x200  maria  1
   x2098 john   2
   a9876 mario  1
```

if i filter the query to show only the customers with M% i want to see

```
   code  name   repeating_numbers
   x1    mike   1
   x200  maria  2
   a9876 mario  1
```

if i want to see the names %o% i need to see

```
   code  name   repeating_numbers
   x1500 George 1
   a9876 mario  2
   x2098 john   1
```

in other words no mater  the filters i need to see numbers 1,2 or maybe 3 in the future, repeat , thank you in advanced

Comment: You need `where like '%%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) with the [modulus operator (`%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql):

```
SELECT code, name, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code ASC) - 1) % 2 + 1 AS repeating_numbers 
FROM customer
```

The same is working with any other number too (like 3):

```
SELECT code, name, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code ASC) - 1) % 3 + 1 AS repeating_numbers 
FROM customer
```

---

You can also use the following to avoid the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT code, name, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) - 1) % 2 + 1 AS repeating_numbers 
FROM customer
```

> **demos:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdae7/6/1